# How to wrap image in anchor tag only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I use this script to wrap an image uploaded with an anchor tag automatically and add the source file of the image to the `href`.

The problem is that every time I edit my page it runs the script again, so if I edit the page 20 times, it would add the anchor wrap 20 times, I need it to run only once OR detect if there is already an anchor tag wrap for the image and not run the script.

```
    <script>
$('.lightbox img').each(function(){
    $(this).wrap(function() {
      return '<a href="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" />';
    })   
});
</script>
```

After I run the script I run this to add an attribute to the anchor tag, how can I make this two scripts only one and run the first one only once.

```
 <script>
$(".lightbox a").attr("data-toggle", "lightbox");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you just need to wrap it once, you need to select only the img tags that are not wrapped in an anchor tag, like

```
$('.lightbox img:not(a>img)').each(function(){
    $(this).wrap(function() {
        return '<a href="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" data-toggle="lightbox" />';
    })   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean as a global variable, like

var flag = true;

Now, set the condition before the execution, Like

```
if(flag){  
   $('.lightbox img').each(function(){
       $(this).wrap(function() {
         return '<a href="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" />';
       }) 

   });
  flag=false;    
  }
```